# monacaでのファイル選択

Tags: javascript, ios, android, monaca, html

ユーザにファイルを選んでもらい、
そのファイルのアドレスを取得するアプリを作っています。
`＜input type="file" id="temp">`
でファイル選択のダイアログを開くボタンを作り
`document.getElementById("temp").value`
でファイルのアドレスを取得したいのですが
スマートフォンで実際にファイル選択を行うと
アドレスが`fakepath`となりアドレスが取得できません。
解決策、別の方法はありますか？

Comment: stackoverflowに類似の質問がありましたので、参考までにご連絡いたします。http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201362/input-type-file-alternative-in-cordova-app

Answer (score 1):

ブラウザからアドレスの取得はセキュリティの関係上出来ません。
cameraプラグインや、fileプラグインなどを使用して
ファイルを選択してもらいましょう。